# Node.js: Using multiple moustache templates

Tags: node.js, mustache

I'm trying to break a moustache template up into various components so I can reuse them, and get the assembled text returned through node.js. I cannot find anyone that has done this.

I can return must ache pages imply with:

```
function index(request, response, next) {
    var stream = mu.compileAndRender('index.mu', 
        {name: "Me"}
        );
    util.pump(stream, response);
}
```

I just cannot figure out how to render a template and use it in another template. I've tried rendering it separately like this:

```
function index(request, response, next) {
    var headerStream = mu.compileAndRender('header.mu', {title:'Home page'});
    var headerText;

    headerStream.on('data', function(data) {
       headerText = headerText + data.toString();
    });

    var stream = mu.compileAndRender('index.mu',        
        {
            heading: 'Home Page',
            content: 'hello this is the home page',
            header: headerText
        });
    util.pump(stream, response);
}
```

But the problem is that the header is not rendered before the page and even if I get that to happen. The header is seen as display text rather than html.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the lines `var stream = ...` and `util.pump(...` in `headerStream.on('end', function () { /* here */ });`, so that they are ran after the `headerStream` has sent all the data to your `data` listener.

To include raw HTML you have to use the triple braces: `{{{raw}}}` in your template as  http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html states.

Comment: I tried that but still ran into problems. The first being what if I want to include more than one other template. And the second is that the include html is rendered as text ('<' becomes &lt;) rather than included as raw text.

Answer (score 0):

The moustache guys came back with the answer. I can do it by using partials like this:

```
{{> index.mu}}
```

Inside the moustache template rather than trying to do it in node.js.